# Windows Forms - Validate DataGridView input

Tags: windows, validation, datagridview, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a Windows Forms application with a DataGridView in one of the forms. The DataGridView can insert and update through a Typed Data Set generated by Visual Studio.

I want to show user friendly error messages when a user doesnt fill in a required field or enters the wrong data type, etc. instead of the ugly huge one that is shown by default.

This page [here](http://tonesnotes.com/blog/2005/05/datagridview_validation.html) gives some guidance. It advises me to validate input on my data sources property setters.

How can I do this with a typed dataset? I am used to working with Linq To Sql, which generated partial classes, but I am not sure about typed datasets.

Thanks.

Comment: This really sucks how difficult it is to validate these fields in a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of winforms visual feedback, I think you should look at a concept like the [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx).

If you are only focusing on input validation, like a string into an integer field this is a good approach, but please, please be aware that real validation of non-trivial mistakes shouldn't be enforced by winform's control validation event model!  For example, 'EndDate < StartDate', really should be pushed down into the business layer.

Comment: This is trivial. Your link is messed up. I don't really understand your answer.

Comment: Fixed the link,not sure what happened there.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

I made a generic user-friendly error message for basic validations using this code:

```
dataGrid.DataError += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        e.ThrowException = false;
        MessageBox.Show(this,
            String.Format("Invalid {0}",
                dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText),
            "Error");
    }
};
```

From MSDN: [Walkthrough: Handling Errors that Occur During Data Entry in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4a23xx4.aspx)